# Typescript function using generics and rest properties doesn't automatic collect all possible types

Tags: typescript, rest, generics

Please see this minimum code below.

```js
function zip<T>(...arrs: T[][]): T[][] {
  return arrs
}

zip([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)

zip<number | string>([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
// Ok, but a little bit bother to me.
```

I created a function using `generics` and `rest` properties.

When I directly use `zip([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])`, I expect that typescript automatically finds out I'm using `number | string` type, is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: That's doing the right thing now. You've defined a function that zips arrays of the same type, your arrays are of different types, so you get an error. You *should* have to add information (like the explicit union type) if that's actually the behaviour you want.

Comment: I think I got it right now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript sees the first parameter is `number[]` and this fixes `T` and then you get an error for the second. While in theory `T` could be inferred to `string | number` I would argue the current behavior is usually a good thing, it is more likely infering unions would lead to unexpected errors in other places.

You can get the compiler to accept the call you want if you make the compiler consider all the arguments as a whole, not individually, using tuples in rest parameters:

```
function zip<T extends any[][]>(...arrs: T): (T[number][number])[][] {
    return arrs
}

zip([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

`T` will be a tuple type for the sample call (`[number[], string[]]`, so to get the item type we use `T[number][number]` (which will be `string | number` for the sample call), and the get back to the array of arrays using `[][]`